# getting error as Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService

Tags: soap, error, ui

while creating the contact in SOAP UI using the enterprise/parter wsdl we are getting the error as : Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService

Please what wil be the end point which need to be changed in SOAP UI before sending create/update/upsert request to SF.

Answer (score 3):

After you do the login call you get a loginresult.

you need to set the endpoint to the serverurl from the loginresult

as a quick example (not complete code per se but just to illustrate):

```
WSDL_partner_soap.Soap sp = new WSDL_partner_soap.Soap();
//do login and get result
WSDL_partner_soap.LoginResult lr = sp.login(*username*, *password*);
sp.endpoint_x = lr.serverURL; //Set URL to returned endpoint

//Set headers to with results from login
WSDL_partner_soap.SessionHeader_element sh = New WSDL_partner_soap.SessionHeader_Element();
sh.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
sp.SessionHeader = sh;
```

Since all the classes that make a call to SF are inner classes they share the same values for the endpoint_x, headers, etc (if you look at the wsdl. so when doing a login you need to reset the values for them or you will get the message you received

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the serverUrl returned from the login step call which resembles something as below :

`<serverUrl>https://instance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0/00Dj0000000I5OP/0DF15000000Pblx</serverUrl>`

Put this serverUrl as the endpoint of your Request as displayed in image below for CREATE call

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the relevant content from any links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your 'myDomain' and change the https://login.salesforce.com/...

to
your domain - eg:
https://mindful-panda-domai-dev-ed.trailblaze.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/59.0/

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that this question is 8 years old at this point. While it does appear that "myDomain" was available at the time (earliest reference I could find would've been around the Summer '13 release), it's not clear if OP was using it at that point. Please review [answer]. You should also consider providing more details (this site _thrives_ on details).